# How to override parent form mapping in a child form?

Tags: java, spring, post, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Sorry for the title, not sure how to word it. I have a form which displays some data in a table.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/do/stuff}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
    <table>
        ....
        <tr th:each="currentFoo : *{fooList}">

        <td>...<td>
        <td>
            <a th:href="'/anotherPage/' + ${currentFoo.getId()}">
               <button>Go to Different page</button>
            </a> 
        </td>
     ...
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/do/stuff", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processQuery(@ModelAttribute FooWrapper wrapper, Model model){....}

@RequestMapping(value="anotherPage/{fooID}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getClient(@PathVariable int id, Model model){...}
```

The problem is that when I click on the button "Go to Different Page", the form is posted and picked up by the mapping `/do/stuff`.

How can I have a button which simply takes me to a completely different page, passing an ID via `get` (think of it as having an option to edit an entry along with the standard option to post all the entries)? I just need to reach the page `anotherPage/{fooID}`

I have tried adding a button-form, in the hopes that it would override the parent form and do a `get` request to the mapping that I wanted, but it didn't work, it all gets picked up by outer form.

```
<form th:action="'/anotherPage/' + ${currentFoo.getID()}" style="display: inline" th:method="get">
    <input type="submit" th:value="Go to Page" role="button" />
</form>
```

Is this even possible? I could even change the child method to `post` if I had to, but the parent form cannot change. 
Any suggestions?

**Update** - I have found and posted a solution but I am unable to accept until tomorrow!

Comment: is it possible to pull the "Go to Different Page" button outside the form?

Comment: @ndrone I don't think so as the button needs to be generated dynamically for each row in the table, and I am pretty sure that I can't 'split' the table by ending the form tag before the `</table>`, as java spring wont let you break up the `<table>...</table>` tags in a form (its all or nothing) - if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a very simple solution. I think the `<button>...</button>` elements when clicked, as they were inside the form they were causing the postback, regardless of the URL specified.

However, using a simple hyperlink and dressing it as a button solved the problem:

```
<a th:href="'/anotherPage/' + ${currentFoo.getID()}" class="btn btn-default">Go to page</a>
```